# How to correct my python3 environment on Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

Tags: python, linux

I tried to install the mysql connector for my python environment.
I use python on my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) machine.
On this machine python 2.7.12 and python 3.5.2.
I probably messed something up because of my inexperience with installing new python modules.
When I now try to install the mysql connector with the command

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

I get the following messages:

> Collecting mysql-connector-python-rf   Downloading
>   mysql-connector-python-rf-2.2.2.tar.gz (11.9MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 11.9MB 131kB/s  Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-connector-python-rf   Running
>   setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-connector-python-rf ... done   Stored
>   in directory:
>   /home/claude/.cache/pip/wheels/bb/53/e4/dced82f8a15f96a8afbe626ebb2939d2901b29e610a97fc1ba
>   Successfully built mysql-connector-python-rf Installing collected
>   packages: mysql-connector-python-rf Exception: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 784, in install
>       **kwargs   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)   File
>   "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line
>   345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line
>   316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)   File "/home/claude/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql_connector_python_rf-2.2.2.dist-info'

**How can a correct this problem?
Or How can I do a correct fresh install of my python2 and python3 environment on my Ubuntu 16.04 x86 Linux?**

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your installation. To install packages globally, you need superuser privileges; you would run that command under `sudo`.

However, you should avoid doing this. Create a virtualenv and install the package there.

Comment: `pip install --username mysql-connector-python-rf` should be avoid too ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Either use sudo, or - preferably - do this inside a virtualenv.

Comment: i meant `pip install --user mysql-connector-python-rf`... it could work to install package without `sudo`

Comment: I used the command: sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf and it worked. Thanks for your help.